# Completeness of ${C^2[0,1]}$ with under a specific metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Prove that ${C^2[0,1]} $ (set of two times differentiable functions)is complete with metric: $$d(f,g)=\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|+ \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f'(x)-g'(x)| + \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f''(x)-g''(x)|.$$

What I have trouble is taking a Cauchy sequence in the space and proving that it converges in that space. The second part of my question is proving that $$S=\{f(x)\in \mathbb{C^2[0,1]} \mid {\textstyle \int_{0}^{1}}f(x)dx\leq 3\} \subset {C^2[0,1]}$$ is complete under this metric. I am told to prove:

> If we have $\{f_n\}\subset S$ with $f_n \to f$ in ${C^2[0,1]}$, then $f \in S$.

Why is this true? Can anyone prove these?

Comment: by the way, it should be $S:=\left\{f(x)| f\in\mathbb{C^2[0,1]} \text{ st } \    \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx\leq 3\right\}$? otherwise S is not necessarily a subset of $\mathbb{C^2[0,1]}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**

Use two ingredients to prove the completness of $\mathcal C^2([0,1])$:

1. **Ingredient one** the space $\mathcal C([0,1]$ of continuous real functions defined on $[0,1]$ is complete for the $\Vert f \Vert =\sup\limits_{x \in [0,1]} \vert f(x) \vert$ norm.
2. **Ingredient two** if a sequence of differentiable functions $(f_n)$ is such that $f_n^\prime$ converges uniformly to $g$ and $f_n(x_0)$ converge for at least one point $x_0 \in [0,1]$ then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ which is differentiable and $f^\prime=g$.

Some possible steps for the recipe.

1. Take a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)$.
2. By definition of your norm, $(f_n)$, $(f_n^\prime)$ and $(f_n^{\prime \prime})$ are Cauchy sequences.
3. With ingredient 1, they converge uniformly to continuous functions $f$, $g$ and $h$ respectively.
4. With ingredient 2, $g$ is differentiable and $g^\prime=h$.
5. Again with ingredient 2 $f$ is differentiable and $f^\prime=g$.
6. You can then conclude.

Regarding the second part of your question, prove that $S$ is closed.

Comment: Ingredient one needs some spices, you should add a metric

Comment: I agree and i would apreciate some instructions on mixing these ingredients.

Comment: You should try some free cooking first... Just a hint: take a Cauchy sequence and start from the second derivative.

Comment: I need cooking lessons, because I take a Cauchy sequence, and have no clue what to do with it. Honest. Completeness it the most problematic area for me.

Comment: By the way, your site is quite impressive.

Comment: Thanks. I added some steps for the proof.

Comment: I have one confusion: You state : **By definition of your norm, (fn), (f′n) and (f′′n) are Cauchy sequences.** A Cauchy sequence in $X$ is a  sequence $x_n$ such that : $(\forall \mathcal{E} > 0 )(\exists n_0 \in \mathbb N) \text{ such from } (m \geq n_0)(n \geq n_0) \implies d(x_n,x_m)< \mathcal{E}$ but for instance with $(f_n)'$, how can we justify that $d(f_n',f_m')< \mathcal E$ when$f_n , f_m $might  not be three times differentiable(I mention this because of the definition of the norm that is given, at the end if would be$d(f_n',f'_m)=...+\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|(f_n')'' - (f_m')''|$)?? Help ?

Comment: If $d(f_n,f_m) <\epsilon$ then $\Vert f_n -f_m \Vert <\epsilon$ and $\Vert f_n^\prime -f_m^\prime \Vert <\epsilon$ and $\Vert f_n^{\prime \prime} -f_m^{\prime \prime} \Vert <\epsilon$ with the notation of my post.

Comment: Functions of $\mathcal C^2([0,1)$ are twice differentiable by definition.

Comment: What confuses me first is $d(f_n, f_m)$ that you mention in the second last post of yours the same metric I defined, either way, how do you conclude from there that $\| f'_n - f'_m \|< \epsilon $ and $\| f''_n - f''_m \|< \epsilon $. This is the only thing that isn't clear to me.

Comment: I finally understand why, thank you for all your help and patience.