# Proving that $S^c=\left\{f(x)\in C^2[0,1]\;\Big\vert\; \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx > 3\right\}$ is open in $C^2[0,1]$ with a specific metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove that $$S^c=\left\{f(x)\in C^2[0,1]\;\Big\vert\; \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx > 3\right\}$$ is open in $C^2[0,1]$ with the metric $d$ given by 
$$ d(f,g)=\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|+ \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f'(x)-g'(x)| + \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f''(x)-g''(x)|.$$

I have trouble with finding a specific $r$ such that when I take $a(x)\in S: $

$B(a(x),r)\subset S , \ \  B(a(x),r)=\{g(x) | d(g(x), a(x))<r\}$

Comment: Hint: If $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$, then the integrals of $f$ and $g$ over $[0,1]$ also differ by less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Im aware, and had this in mind, but I cant put this together.

Comment: The map $\phi(f) = \int_0^1f$ is a bounded linear functional on $C^2;$ hence $\phi$ is continuous and therefore $\phi^{-1}((3,\infty))$ is open in $C^2.$

Comment: I see. Brilliant.

Comment: Type it out as an answer. That is definitely worth some rep.

Comment: If you had to prove that it is a continuous linear functional, you would need exactly the same argument I was hinting at above... (And if you know all of these terms and the fact that bounded linear functionals are continuous, I really don't quite understand your confusion here.)

Comment: Try to show its complement is closed , by sequential approach..

Comment: The sequential approach being ?

Comment: Hint: try to show that the complement of $S$ is closed. This will be much easier.

Comment: The original was exactly that. I know now how to prove the openness of the set in question(literally), I was just curious as to the sequential approach

Comment: In [a previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379372/completeness-of-c20-1-with-under-a-specific-metric) you have shown that $S$ is closed. Thus, its complement is open.

Comment: I have not shown that. That is why I opened this question.